# how can I create a form for User model which can be updated after successfully logged into application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

**Requirement:** I need to create an application where user can logged in and can change the background color of that page, can change the font of the page and it should persist with session. so I am trying to create form which accept those attributes from user and can save in database. I am using devise for authentication.

How can I create form for user who is successfully logged into application(authentication is done by devise gem, so user table is already existing) and upon submission of form those attributes should get updated in user table. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Q1 .What should be the name of controller and view for this form ?

Q2. How the routes can be define.

Q3. Whether controller should have update action to update user table with the extra attributes present in the form.

Thanks. Please comment below if I missed some information needed to provide. You can suggest me if you think this can be achieve in easier way also.

Comment: Have you considered that the attributes you want to edit after the user is created are a different Model?  Are you actually creating UserPreferences, for example?  Adding a new scaffold might simplify this problem.  New models don't 'cost' anything.

Comment: @JoeEssey No the attribute is for user who logged into the application and belongs to user model only. I created migration for user and added attributes in the table and now I need to create a form and get those attributes from form and save in user table. Hope I gave your answer.

Comment: I like Joe's answer actually cyborg.   When a user is created, all attributes necessary for that user should exist in that form.   You can add any you need to expand Devise.   Maybe that's what you really want?   Better, what exactly is the field you're discussing?   I would think if it's not part of user creation, why not have it in another model.

Comment: @JoeEssey   ok guys let me clarify, the requirement is: I need to create an application where user can logged in and can change the background color of that page, can change the font of the page and it should persist with session. so I am trying to create form which accept those attributes from user and can save in database. I am using devise for authentication. let me know if u need any more information. I have posted multiple times this question but not received any working solution, so please guide me.

Comment: @cyborg, I don't mean to assume that I have provided the best answer, but I will pass on some knowledge that was shared with me when I started here.  Beware the XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Whatever you want.  Sounds li?ke you are just updated user attributes, so i would just use the User#update action
2. resources :users, only: [:update, :edit] #and any other user routes
3. ? see 1

Also you will want to make sure that people can only edit their own account.  In a before action  you will want to add.

redirect_to root_path unless current_user == user_you_are_editing

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I am trying out . Will update soon

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

1. Create a Model called `UserPreferences` that `belongs_to :user`, give this Model the attributes 'background_color', etc...
2. Add statement to user `has_one :user_preferences`
3. Create a form for the prefs like any Rails Model, that can only be accessed by current_user.
4. Use current_user.user_preferences to refer to these values, you can enhance this by placing alias methods in User, for example:

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base

       def background_color
          self.user_preferences.background_color
       end
   end
   ```

Comment: let me try this, and will update you if I am successful or else will come up with error report soon. :)  be tuned... by the way thanks for your effort

Comment: really better to just use delegate.  i.e. a call like delegate :background_color, :background_color= to: :user_preferences

Comment: @Austio, Thank you, that is the first I've heard of delegate in Rails!

Comment: @JoeEssey, np happy that it will help you :)